# couldn't connect to the data sources using WebSphere Application Server 8.0.5

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

Can someone please help to solve the below issue

I'm using Websphere application Serve 8.0.5 and the port number for WS Default Host set to 9044.

I have added the data sources to the Server and when I try to connect to that it is giving below error

**DSRA8040I: Failed to connect to the DataSource.  Encountered "": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CConnection**

and the IBM console the error is

**"The test connection operation failed for data source xxxx on server at node Node01 with the following exception: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CConnection. View JVM logs for further details"**

When I use the port number 9043 I was able to successfully connected to Data Source. I dont know why it is allowing to login using 9043 as 9043 port number is not specified in the ports list.

Appreciate you help.

Comment: You should locate the Oracle JDBC drivers (they should be a couple of jars) and declare the paths where they are while creating the JDBC Provider for the datasource.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I have alredy declared the jar files in the application server. Is there anything else that is causing the error

Comment: Are you saying that you access the admin console on two different ports and when you test the connection accessing one of the admin console ports it works and when you try it on the other it does not?

Comment: The only explanation for the error you are receiving is really that WAS can't find the driver classes. If you have configured the driver setup and paths as you stated, then the drivers are not where you think they are, there might be a typo somewhere, or they are for some reason not readable to WAS (access rights).